# how to use CXF and ANT to generate Stub from nonlocal wsdl url

Tags: url, wsdl, cxf, stub

I would like to have ANT script (not Maven) to generate Stub from wsdl url.I know how to do that if the file wsdl stays in my local (c drive), but not able to do that when wsdl stays remotely.

Please help.

Comment: With _lots_ of hard-earned (and painful) experience, I always copy WSDL and XSD documents to local files before passing them through WSDL-to-Java converters. The reason why? You just can't rely on the network being up. Or the service's network being up. Or some incidentally-referred-to service being up (the W3C schemas are typical problems here!) I know it is more work to set up, but it is so much less painful later on; builds failing for apparently no fault of your own is a _terrible_ thing when it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
   <target name="cxfWSDLToJava">
      <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
         <arg value="-client"/>
         <arg value="-d"/>
         <arg value="src"/>
         <arg value="http://somehost.com/service?wsdl"/>
         <classpath>
            <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
         </classpath>
      </java>
   </target>
```